The moderator blocked user accounts due to voting violations
The situation occurred with two accounts: self SVBazuev and my daughter's AnnaBazueva.
When she sees a question that she can answer, she does it.
We often use one device, it happens like this:

I look at the answers she gave, sometimes she sends me a link to her answer.

If I have comments, I voice them and she corrects them (see the history of edits of answers).
When I have no comments and I find her answer acceptable, I vote for her answer.

Other community members can also vote for Anna's answers, both UP and DOWN.
I would like to draw your attention to the fact that at the moment none of her answers
have been voted against even once!
This circumstance is indirect evidence that my votes have a basis (they are not a mechanical cheat on Anna's reputation).


In addition to my daughter, I also have a son, Gregory, who is 14 and a half years old,
and soon three accounts will use one device.
I voted for my daughter's answers, and because of this, our accounts are blocked.
I find it useful to reduce the cost of follower (In the sense of allies) votes from 10 to 2 reputation points. This should significantly improve the situation with reputation cheating.
So that it is possible to link accounts into groups, and within the group there are other prices per vote.
And moderators could mark (forcibly make allies) accounts between which cross-voting is observed.
Should this be implemented?

How about just not voting on your daughter's answers. As you say, the community can do it so leave it to them.

This still seems like targeted voting to me (even if it's not outright sock puppetry).

@RobertLongson She is not yet 16 years old, this is such a game between us on mastering StackOverflow...

Whilst you seem genuine, we see many people trying to cheat the system and making excuses here. Best to contact the staff to sort it out.

It's not clear to me what you're asking here. The majority of your question is explaining why you engaged in voting fraud, for which the accounts were suspended. That's not something which anyone here can help you with, other than to say "don't do that". If you want to bring it up to the moderators on the site, then you need to respond to the moderator messages which were sent with the account suspensions. If you do not feel satisfied with their response and wish to bring it up with the company, then you need to use the "Contact"/"Contact Us" link that is at the bottom of every page.

The small latter portion of your question is what appears to be a [tag:feature-request], although you tagged this [tag:support], suggesting to lower the number of reputation awarded to people from upvotes from 10 to 2 under some conditions (I think when they are following the post????), but what you're suggesting isn't clear to me.

@Makyen No, not when they subscribe to a post, but for those cases when there is a suspicion of reputation fraud. This is an alternative to blocking. Edit my question if I have conveyed the essence incorrectly, please!

@SVBazuev But, while I haven't done an actual survey, I would suspect that the vast majority of people who subscribe to a post are not engaging in, and have no intention to engage in, voting fraud. Why should the authors of posts that are of such particular interest such that others subscribe to the post be penalized by only getting 2 reputation from the upvote that they received from someone who subscribed to the post. [BTW: by "subscribed", I assume you meant "followed"].

@SVBazuev When the meaning of the post is unclear to me, it's not possible for me to edit it to make it clearer without making assumptions as to what you meant, which isn't appropriate. If the meaning was clear to me, it would be possible for me to edit it to try to make the meaning clearer to other people.

NOTE: Just as a forewarning: That your daughter is not yet 16 may be a significant issue for her using the site, as the laws in your location may require that her account and all PII be completely wiped. I strongly support younger people pursuing their interests, particularly in STEM and programming. I consider it very unfortunate that the laws, effectively, force such actions upon Stack Overflow (without Stack Overflow taking on a considerable burden in processing such accounts, which they are just not staffed for). Please continue to encourage your daughter in her interests.

You can consider: “If you wish to use Stack Exchange, we'd encourage you to work with your parent or legal guardian, who can set up an account and use it with you, or establish other appropriate ways to use the site as a family” from this answer

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog These issues are related, but I'm trying to address a separate aspect. Tomorrow I will try to concretize my question.

IMHO you have a clear conflict of interest. What you should (or rather shouldn't do) is rather obvious, no?

@DanMašek You are right, in the concept of sockpuppet is rather obvious that I shouldn't do. However, this concept is very crude and is only supported because it is easier to maintain. In addition, this approach is able to filter out only strong noise from beginners, and the sophisticated will find the means to get what they want. It seems to me that we need to think about a new concept.

I'm not really talking about sock puppets specifically, but the broader concept of conflict of interest. The parent-child relationship makes you inherently biased, no matter your intent. Hence, the ethical way to deal with this situation would be to refrain from any curation activities concerning your child's account (primarily voting). You should still praise her for making good posts, obviously, and explain to her why voting wouldn't be OK. (You'd be in this conundrum even if you were using different computers, that's not the issue)

I get that what you describe isn't intentional voting fraud. Assuming you are indeed doing exactly what you say and only vote if the content is good, then I don't see a problem. In theory.
In practice, however, since the accounts use the same device, we have no way of knowing if you are actually doing what you say or if you are just using three accounts to inflate the reputation of one of them. From our perspective, the two scenarios are indistinguishable.
This means that even though you may only vote on her good answers, the result is two accounts, which appear like they are the same person, voting for each other and that smacks of voting fraud.
I am afraid I don't have a good solution for you other than to ask you to stop doing it. Just don't vote for your children's posts, and make sure they don't vote on yours, and let the community do the voting instead. If you stumble upon one of their posts while using the site and vote on it before you even realize it was theirs, that should be fine, but if they send you specific posts to check you will always give the impression that you're taking part in targeted voting. And, really, you are since you are indeed targeting these specific users. It's just that you are doing it for innocent reasons, so you don't have the intent to commit fraud, but at the end of the day, that's kinda what you're doing.

In my opinion, it doesn't just give the impression of being targeted voting, it is targeted voting (because the OP is voting differently on his daughter's posts than he would on a different user's posts).

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine The OP doesn't say anything like that, they only say that they upvote her content if they find it good, I don't know why you assume they are voting differently on her posts than on others. In any case, I don't say it isn't targeted voting in my answer, in fact, I explicitly say that the OP is taking part in targeted voting.

@terdon There is something to cling to in your answer. Tomorrow I will try to concretize my question.

While this is not sock puppetry, it is still targeted voting. The fact that she's your daughter presumably strongly influences the way you vote on her posts, and it influences your likelihood to vote on it in the first place.
Voting should be based on the content rather than on the user posting the content - that's very fundamental to how Stack Exchange voting is supposed to work. If the identity of the user has that much of an influence on how you'll vote, it's better not to vote on the content at all.

Look at her answers (except for the last one by date, she did not have time to work out the comments received in the comments - she was blocked) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/606213/annabazueva

@SVBazuev The quality of the answers is beside the point. The point is that it's targeted voting (because the identity of the poster is strongly influencing how you vote on the posts). You're supposed to vote purely based on the content (not on the identity of the poster).

I think the 'simple' answer here is - not to interact between accounts in the same household or company/work unit. Don't crossvote, don't comment, don't do suggested edits. Basically if it involves reputation, and accounts of people you know don't
Practically We've no way of telling if cross voting between users in the 'same place' is organic or not, and generally while we don't reveal details on anti fraud measures (and some are opaque for us too) there generally needs to be a pattern of cross voting, and other measures.

I find it useful to reduce the cost of follower (In the sense of allies) votes from 10 to 2 reputation points. This should significantly improve the situation with reputation cheating.

People would simply vote 5 times as much, once they've gotten enough accounts bootstrapped. Its trivial to create an account on SE by design, and sometimes people get 'creative'.
I get the idea that you're trying to use the site as a teaching tool - which is lovely but as you've found out, some aspects of it don't really work well they way you're using it.
Unfortunately, especially with SO, some folks value site reputation enough that there's value in trying to game the system to them, which makes - essentially formalising cross voting impractical. Even if linked account votes didn't count for reputation - a group could push an answer up in visibility inorganically.

I would like to draw your attention to the fact that at the moment none of her answers have been voted against even once!

Which is excellent - and in which case she, and her answers can do just fine from votes from other people.

If I have comments, I voice them and she corrects them (see the history of edits of answers).
When I have no comments and I find her answer acceptable, I vote for her answer.

I'd consider if you'd have come across the answer any other way, and that she's in the same household affects the visibility of the post. This would be the same as if I was in an offsite chatroom, and tended to keep linking my posts to my friends and get upvotes. This is practically... not how the site and voting should work.
I feel like - in this context your daughter and son might understand why dad can't vote for them, and pre-emptively why they shouldn't vote for each other. (I recall, vaguely, that this did happen, and we had someone claim their sibling voted for them to get suspended. The story got stranger after that)


I find it useful to reduce the cost of follower votes from 10 to 2 reputation points.

I don’t understand what you mean for “follower votes”, but I think that you mean to reduce 10 to 2 reputation for upvote.
You said that if the reputation reduced, then there’s no reputation cheating? I don’t agree with the statement you said.
You can also create many accounts and upvote the answer,
but all of your accounts will be suspended.

If you upvote your daughter, that means that your daughter will earn reputation, and maybe earns some new privileges.
Why cheating is bad? Maybe your daughter's answers are not good, but you still give her upvote(s).
My suggestion is just leave the answer, if your daughter’s answers are good, then other users with upvote the questions. If the answers are bad, then other users can downvote them.

After I see the @Qwertiy, I know what happened.
Although your 10 reputation are reduced to 2 reputation, but just the same thing, you still upvote others, still gain reputation, and 5 upvotes= 10 reputation.

He suggest that he proves that he and his dautcher are different people (usure, but maybe he already did) and then he is added in some (now not implemented) followers list for another user, and votes from people from that list should give less points than usual (2 instead of 10 in his proposal).
